# Wait for all except of one process in Bash

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, wait

I have a Bash script which basically looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

command_1 &

command_a &
command_b &
command_c &

wait

echo "done"
```

I execute some commands in background using `&` at the end of the command. Then I wait for the commands to finish with `wait`. But I only want to wait for the commands `a`, `b` and `c`, *not* for `1`. How can I do this? Is it possible to accomplish without collecting the PIDs of command `a`, `b` and `c` in an array and wait for those PIDs`? (That's what I tried so far, but it is kind of complicated.).

Comment: No, there's no way other than keeping the PIDs.

Comment: Mmm... OK... What a shame...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could execute commands a, b, c in a subshell.

```
command_1 &

( command_a & command_b & command_c & wait )

echo "done"
```

If you do not want to execute a, b, c in a subshell, then you need to keep track of the individual PIDs.

Comment: Thanks! I will also post my solution with collecting PIDs.

Comment: +1 Note that there's also little drawback to running in a subshell; since each command runs in a background process, you've already lost the ability to have them affect the current shell.

Answer (score 1):

To complete the list of answers, here is my "old" solution with collecting PIDs:

I execute every command (or a couple of commands) in a subshell and store the PID in an array. After I started all commands, I loop over my array and wait for each PID:

```
#!/bin/bash

INDEX=0

command_1 &

(
    command_a
) &

PIDS[$INDEX]=$!
INDEX=$[INDEX + 1]

(
    command_b
    command_c
) &

PIDS[$INDEX]=$!
INDEX=$[INDEX + 1]

for job in ${PIDS[@]}
do
    echo "wait for $job"
    wait $job
done

echo "done"
```

---

```
command_1 &
command_a & wait_pids+=($!)
command_b & wait_pids+=($!)
command_c & wait_pids+=($!)
wait "${wait_pids[@]}"
```

Comment: This can be done much more simply; I'll add to the bottom and you can edit as you see fit.